# FullCalendar scrolls over website header

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, w3.css

finally got FullCalendar to get events from Google (although I need to leave the key restrictions off; when adding my domain I get API 400 errors). That aside I have a small issue. My "responsive" website (and google integrated Fullcalendar) is here;[www.retina2.co.uk/calendar.html](http://retina2.co.uk/calendar.html)

If you set the width of the screen to less than 993px (I think its 993; medium and small W3.CSS) it will enter medium mode and the sidenav will disappear and a small black header introduced. When scrolling down the page, the active FullCalendar button (e.g. "Month" by default) and the calendar itself scroll OVER the header; you can see the calendar grid/borders, events and button. How to I make sure that the whole calendar scrolls under the header so none of the calendar items are visible when they scroll under the header?

It's a small niggle but it looks messy when this occurs (ie mobile, tablet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i understood you want to keep calendar beneath header. So, in your w3.css file add this block. this will keep the header on top of other elements.

```
header.w3.container.w3-top { 
   z-index:999
}
```

if you have any other issue then let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Shaybi - I currently just link to '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">' so will try downloading W3.css instead and try the above. Back later this afternoon (thanks for the super-quick response) and will let you know how it goes

Comment: for now, to check this you can add <style> tag in on top of your html and put this css block in that tag and it will work.

Comment: aaaah... got it! As I already have some of this added in-line in my , I just added `style="z-index:999"` to my <header> ... working a treat! Thanks - my aesthetics have been satiated

Comment: @OblivionGuest you could upvote the answer you helped (most), please have a look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: I have upvoted but my reputation is too low for it too display (the stackoverflow popup informs me that the vote is recorded just not displayed). I guess that's why I can't upvote a comment - FYI; I have now added this to my imbedded style-sheet in my html as suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: yeah, Good. :-)